# Add rows to data frame in R based on conditions in columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with a column of 22 unique station identifiers with time series data. I want to make a time series bar plot. I can do this fine. However, some stations don't have data for certain months. So some of the plots don't look right because it will only show two months of data instead of all 12. My question is how do I add the missing months and zero values for the stations that are missing. I want to do it in a functional way so I don't have to look through each station and see whats missing manually.

Sample data:

```
  structure(list(month = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "05", "05", "06", "06", 
"06", "07", "07", "07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"08", "08", "08", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12"), Station = c("01377358", "01378560", "01379200", 
"01379525", "01463740", "01463750", "01463810", "1390600", "1390700", 
"1390800", "1399565", "1399820", "1400775", "1401400", "1403075", 
"1408100", "AN0113", "BFBM000180", "BFBM000244", "BFBM000245", 
"BFBM000246", "BFBM000247", "BFBM000248", "FIBI041", "01377358", 
"01378560", "01379525", "01463740", "01463750", "01463810", "1390600", 
"1390700", "1390800", "1399565", "1399820", "1400775", "1401400", 
"1403075", "AN0113", "BFBM000180", "BFBM000245", "BFBM000246", 
"BFBM000247", "BFBM000248", "FIBI041", "01377358", "01378560", 
"01379525", "01463740", "01463750", "01463810", "1390600", "1390700", 
"1390800", "1401400", "1403075", "AN0113", "BFBM000245", "BFBM000246", 
"BFBM000247", "BFBM000248", "FIBI041", "01377358", "01378560", 
"01379525", "1390800", "AN0113", "BFBM000245", "01378560", "01379525", 
"01378560", "01379525", "01463740", "01377358", "01378560", "BFBM000244", 
"BFBM000245", "01377358", "01378560", "01379200", "01379525", 
"AN0113", "BFBM000244", "BFBM000245", "BFBM000246", "BFBM000247", 
"01377358", "01378560", "01379200", "01379525", "AN0113", "BFBM000244", 
"BFBM000245", "BFBM000246", "01377358", "01378560", "01379200", 
"01379525", "BFBM000244", "BFBM000245", "01378560", "01379525", 
"BFBM000244", "BFBM000245", "01377358", "01378560", "01379200", 
"01379525", "01463740", "01463750", "01463810", "1399820", "1403075", 
"AN0113", "BFBM000244", "BFBM000245", "BFBM000246", "BFBM000247", 
"FIBI041"), Huc14 = c("02030103170010", "02030103180010", "02030103010070", 
"02030103010140", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"2030103140010", "HUC02030100000000", "2030103140020", "HUC2030105050080", 
"2030105070010", "2030105100130", "2030105110010", "2030105120050", 
"HUC02040301030010", "02040105240010", "HUC02030100000000", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02030103170010", "02030103180010", "02030103010140", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "2030103140010", 
"HUC02030100000000", "2030103140020", "HUC2030105050080", "2030105070010", 
"2030105100130", "2030105110010", "2030105120050", "02040105240010", 
"HUC02030100000000", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", "02030103180010", 
"02030103010140", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"2030103140010", "HUC02030100000000", "2030103140020", "2030105110010", 
"2030105120050", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", 
"02030103180010", "02030103010140", "2030103140020", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02030103180010", "02030103010140", "02030103180010", 
"02030103010140", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", "02030103180010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", "02030103180010", 
"02030103010070", "02030103010140", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", 
"02030103180010", "02030103010070", "02030103010140", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02030103170010", 
"02030103180010", "02030103010070", "02030103010140", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02030103180010", "02030103010140", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02030103170010", "02030103180010", "02030103010070", 
"02030103010140", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"2030105070010", "2030105120050", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", 
"02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010", "02040105240010"
), `Total Number of Exceedance` = c(1028, 1362, 870, 1294, 595, 
589, 484, 1419, 1417, 1416, 564, 535, 46, 411, 1463, 25, 827, 
1343, 476, 1455, 718, 603, 2, 295, 1344, 1298, 1343, 349, 567, 
500, 1344, 1344, 1344, 428, 685, 5, 661, 1344, 940, 886, 1173, 
272, 802, 304, 201, 1488, 1416, 1437, 504, 698, 568, 1322, 842, 
856, 86, 901, 1324, 791, 549, 794, 447, 602, 209, 1164, 625, 
68, 384, 483, 980, 68, 970, 189, 1, 307, 7, 114, 112, 1069, 52, 
253, 62, 4, 1472, 1478, 2, 93, 890, 488, 1039, 48, 19, 1194, 
1389, 12, 7, 618, 203, 578, 1483, 1466, 777, 644, 1439, 1396, 
495, 1244, 462, 1008, 125, 5, 86, 26, 17, 74, 1403, 1451, 89, 
263, 1), timehrs = c(514, 681, 435, 647, 297.5, 294.5, 242, 709.5, 
708.5, 708, 282, 267.5, 23, 205.5, 731.5, 12.5, 413.5, 671.5, 
238, 727.5, 359, 301.5, 1, 147.5, 672, 649, 671.5, 174.5, 283.5, 
250, 672, 672, 672, 214, 342.5, 2.5, 330.5, 672, 470, 443, 586.5, 
136, 401, 152, 100.5, 744, 708, 718.5, 252, 349, 284, 661, 421, 
428, 43, 450.5, 662, 395.5, 274.5, 397, 223.5, 301, 104.5, 582, 
312.5, 34, 192, 241.5, 490, 34, 485, 94.5, 0.5, 153.5, 3.5, 57, 
56, 534.5, 26, 126.5, 31, 2, 736, 739, 1, 46.5, 445, 244, 519.5, 
24, 9.5, 597, 694.5, 6, 3.5, 309, 101.5, 289, 741.5, 733, 388.5, 
322, 719.5, 698, 247.5, 622, 231, 504, 62.5, 2.5, 43, 13, 8.5, 
37, 701.5, 725.5, 44.5, 131.5, 0.5)), .Names = c("month", "Station", 
"Huc14", "Total Number of Exceedance", "timehrs"), row.names = c(NA, 
-119L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Example plot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: The `dplyr` library has a function called `complete` which will fill in missing rows for unrepresented factor levels.

Comment: Does `data %>% complete(month, Station)` work for you?

Comment: @Mako212 Yes it does thanks. How would I get the NAs that it creates to become zeros for the other columns?

Comment: You can additionally specify the values to fill with by passing the values in a list like so: `data %>% complete(month, Station, fill = list('Total Number of Exceedance' = 0, 'Huc14' = 0, 'timehrs' = 0))`

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks so much! Your awesome!